# Could there be an option to ask questions anonymously?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I've often wanted to ask some questions or post comments and answers here but refrained because I didn't want my current employer to find them.

I understand that we don't want to have too many anonymous questions so maybe you could only use the option if you have a certain number of reputation and/or sacrifice some reputation to use the feature.

What do you think?

Comment: See also: [Should there be an option to post anonymously?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79390/should-there-be-an-option-to-post-anonymously), [Allow anonymization of posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31741/allow-anonymization-of-posts), [Need to ask a question anonymously.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89248/need-to-ask-a-question-anonymously)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to post questions without creating an account. Simply log out, and when posting your question create a random display name and use an old email address.

Note that posting a question in this fashion has some restrictions:

- Post is quality checked by the system
- No new tags can be created
- You must supply both an email address and display name

Obviously you will also fail to gain any reputation or badges related to that question should it gain them.

I took the liberty of creating an example question, see [Example Anon Question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/81913/example-anon-question). I'll delete this after you take a look.

Comment: An example question was perhaps not the best approach. ;)

Comment: I just noticed the many flags on that question. Who would think that a question with the title *"Example Anon Question"* and locked by a moderator would be considered low quality...

Comment: When I saw it I immediately thought it was a from a user that was clueless, especially because it was already locked.  If the user associated to it was a mod, I would have paused longer to see that it was being used for something.  Perhaps a comment (which Anna has added) would have helped the confusion on our part.

Comment: That's a good idea, I hadn't thought about it. Obviously, I'm more interested in the answer here than the reputation points so I might do it that way.

Comment: @Walter: In hindsight I should have added a comment linking to this meta post.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an account to ask a question, so one way to do it would be to open up an "incognito" window if you use Chrome and post your question. You could also use a different browser or sign out of your account. Make sure you log out of your OpenID provider as well, to avoid being automatically signed back in to SE.

You could also register a second account. That is allowed so long as there is no interaction between your accounts - that is, if someone attempts to game the system by creating accounts to upvote their main account's posts, we will find out and merge the accounts together. If the accounts never interact, there's nothing to worry about.